# Flow chart for Upgrade of Sitecore 8.1 Commerce Server to Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0.2

Tags: sitecore-commerce, upgrade

I have added the diagrammatic representation for the upgrade. Please let me know your thoughts and if I need to add or follow certain additional steps while doing the upgrade.
[image]

Comment: You are missing migration of contact data between Sitecore versions. Take a look here -> https://doc.sitecore.net/xdb_data_migration_tool

Comment: Also don't forget that first you need to upgrade from Sitecore (Commerce) 8.1 to 8.2 as Migration tool only supports path from 8.2.x to 9.0.2 -> https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Commerce/90/Sitecore_Experience_Commerce_90_Update2.aspx#

Comment: Thanks @PeterProchazka for your views but I do see in http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Migration/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Data-Migration-Guide.pdf they have mentioned on "1.1 Initial assumption" section that "These instructions apply to Sitecore Commerce systems 8.2 or older. Data migration from Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 solutions is not supported.  ". So i guess with this I can migrate from 8.1

Comment: Exactly @Amitabh . You are on Sitecore 8.1 therefore you first need to upgrade to 8.2 in order to use that Migration tool ;)

Comment: My bad I took it the other way. Then what exactly I should do to upgrade it from Sitecore Commerce 8.1? I do understand one option is to upgrade it to 8.2 and then to 9 with help of the commerce migration tool but I hope there may be some other easier or better way to do so

Comment: I am afraid that this is the only upgrade path possible Sitecore 8.1 -> Sitecore 8.2 -> Sitecore 9.0.2

Comment: Sitecore Upgrade from 8.1 to 9.0.2 is possible but the issue is with Commerce Server as the Commerce migration tool only supports from 8.2 or older. So I guess if the manual creation of the Catalog, Category and all other properties done we can skip the upgrade path of 8.2. I guess this would not have any challenges and would be straight forward. What is your thought on this @PeterProchazka